# fetching data from combobox list in vaadin

Tags: sql-server-2008, vaadin

Kindly correct this code ;

I have a combobox which is developed in Vaadin framework and connected to a SQL Server. It has 3 static values 5,3,1 year respectively, kindly help me to add listeners to these 3 options and tell me how code when a value (Ex = 5 years) is selected, it should display all the value from last 5 years like wise for 3 years and 1 year, kindly help me.

```
comboDateOrigine.addListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {

            public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) 
            {
               if (event.getProperty().getValue() != null) 
               {

                    if(event.getProperty().getValue().toString() == "5 Ans"){
                        comboDateOrigine.select(ListOptions.get(0));
                      SELECT DateOrigine from WebProject
                      where DateOrigine = (Current date - (5years ) )

                    }
                    else if(comboDateOrigine.getValue().toString() == "3 years"){
                         comboDateOrigine.select(ListOptions.get(1));
                         SELECT DateOrigine from WebProject
                      where DateOrigine = (Current date - (3 years ) )

                    }
                    else if(comboDateOrigine.getValue().toString() == "1 year"){
                        comboDateOrigine.select(ListOptions.get(2));
                         SELECT DateOrigine from WebProject
                      where DateOrigine = (Current date - (1years ) )

                    }
                }
                else{
                    // Reset the ComboBox
                    comboDateOrigine.setValue(null);
                }
            }
        });
    comboDateOrigine.setImmediate(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I suggest to use

```
comboDateOrigine.addValueChangeListener(new ValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        //...
    }
);
```

Then to get the value selected, I don't know how this combo is made (custom made item, item got from databse, etc) but

```
comboDateOrigine.getValue();
```

gives the value of the property used as "id". If your combobox uses a "complex" item maybe you can get a better property to do the query, like

```
Item selectedItem = comboDateOrigine.getContainerDataSource().getItem(comboDateOrigine.getValue());
Integer year = (Integer)selectedItem.getItemProperty("year").getValue();
```

For references about manipulate dates here's a little snippet

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(date);
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
c.getTime(); //-> gives the date+1 back
```

About the actual query look at PreparedStatement class & co.
This should be a good starting point.